# How to specify lib directory for ant task?

Tags: ant

I'm currently running an exec task in my build like this:

```
<target name="bar">
  <exec executable="ant">
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <arg value="/path/to/my/build.xml"/>
    <arg value="-lib"/>
    <arg value="/path/to/my/libs"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

I don't really like it and want to replace the exec task with an ant task:

```
<target name="bar">
  <ant antfile="/path/to/my/build.xml"/>
</target>
```

However, I don't know how to specify the lib directory in this case. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What is your real goal? the `ant` task is the `GOTO` of ant. It is almost always going to lead you to a mess.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve, by launching ANT from within ANT in this manner?

For example if you need custom ANT extensions, the path to these jars can be specified at runtime within the code as follows:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Better again, you could integrate a dependency management system like [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage 3rd party jar dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ant script inside an ant script like below.
If you use the attribute inheritrefs="true" any  Ids that are set in the parent build script will be passed to child build script as well.

Eg:

```
<ant antfile="subbuild.xml" inheritrefs="true"/>
```